# Solution to Blocking system call by worker thread in Node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, process, operating-system, libuv

I recently learnt about user level threads and kernel level threads in Operating System book by tanenbaum. Since user level threads are handled by library packages and since had worked with node.js a bit, i concluded that node.js uses libuv for handling worker threads and hence uses user level threading.

But I wanted to know how node.js deals with the case when some worker thread makes a system call that is blocking and then the kernel will block the entire process even if some threads are capable of running.

Comment: What system calls do you think block the entire process, even other threads in the process?

Comment: @jfriend00 If a thread causes a page fault, the kernel, unaware of even the existence of threads, naturally blocks the entire process until the disk I/O is complete, even though other threads might be runnable. Page Fault causes blocking because page needs to be brought in memory from disk.

Comment: And, when do you expect nodejs would be causing Page Faults?

Comment: @jfriend00 what do you think is a page? If you feel i am wrong at something please tell. If you know the answer or there is any confusion tell. But I don't like this round and round way of asking and answering.

Comment: You're the one that first used the "page fault".  What do you think it is in your comment?  There's no effort to go round and round here.  You seem to think that nodejs can get blocked for long periods of time and I'm trying to get you to say how/when you think that can happen? I've never heard of this as a problem in nodejs at the OS/system level like you describe so I'm asking you to explain why you think it is a problem? The onus here is on you to create a clear question that we can  attempt to help with. As your question stands now, I've never heard of that issue being a problem in nodejs.

Comment: @jfriend00 okay, here is my attemp at making things clear. This is what i know: Node.js is a single threaded runtime environment for JavaScript. Single Threaded means OS kernel will see only single process handling all incoming requests to server using node at back-end. To overcome it's single threaded nature, it uses libuv library to create worker threads so that it only accepts and passes requests to worker threads. As i said, since a library is being used to provide multithreading, these are user-level threads and not kernel level threads.

Comment: Now suppose one of the worker threads needs to gather data that is in disk. So kernel will block the entire process untill the worker threads disk request is not completed. The complete process gets blocked because the kernel is not aware of threads. It only sees the single process that accepts the requests. So as long as the I/O is not completed no further requests can be accepted. Is there any problem in my understanding? If not then isn't it bad that a single I/O request would stop other requests from being accepted ?

Comment: Your assumption that the kernel will block the entire process because there's one disk access under way  is not how I think any modern OS works.  I'm not sure where you got that from.

Comment: Also, independent of what the kernel does, nodejs uses OS level threads (via libuv) for various things internally.  One of those things it uses these threads for is disk access so that accessing a disk does not unnecessarily block the Javascript execution thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I wanted to know how node.js deals with the case when some worker thread makes a system call that is blocking and then the kernel will block the entire process even if some threads are capable of running.

This isn't what happens in a modern OS.  Just because one thread in a process is reading/writing from the disk, the OS does NOT block the entire process from doing anything with its other threads.

Modern hardware uses [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) (Direct Memory Access) for reading/writing to disks precisely so that the CPU does not have to be blocked while a block of data is read from or written to a disk.